# Updated Castle to 3.2.1 from 3.0.0 now I cant use FirstNonGenericCoreInterface

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container, fluent-interface, s#arp-architecture

After I upgraded Castle to 3.2.1 I cant seem to find the right replacement for FirstNonGenericCoreInterface

My codes

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes
        .FromAssemblyNamed("MySolution.Tasks")
        .InNamespace("MySolution.Tasks")
        .WithService.FirstNonGenericCoreInterface("MySolution.Domain"));
```

That method is not obsolete and I cannot find what method to use

[image]

**Does anyone know what should I use instead?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, FirstNonGenericCoreInterface is a Sharp Architecture extension method.

WithService.DefaultInterfaces() should do what you need if your implementation class names match the interfaces. More info is available on the Castle Windsor wiki http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Registering-components-by-conventions&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1